# How do i get the same result without using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, vector, subtraction

I hear for loops in R are slow so I was wondering how to simplify this to speed things up. I want to subtract 1 from every element in connections, but if it is already zero, i don't want to keep subtracting and make it negative.

```
for(i in 1:length(connections)) {
    if(connections[i] > 0) {
      connections[i] = connections[i] - 1
    }
    if(connections[i] < 0) {
      connections[i] = 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to keep the max of (connections - 1) and 0.

```
pmax(connections - 1, 0)
```

Comment: wow thanks that sped things up significantly... at least 2x faster lol

Comment: 2x? I haven't measured but I wouldn't be surprised if it were 10x faster. Also, to let people know that your question has been answered, click the check mark next to the answer that best fit your needs. Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers that are already posted, a short benchmark with the results on my machine (Intel Core i5-8400 2.80GHz, 16GB RAM):

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  #Subtract 1 from values > 0
  ind <- x > 0
  x[ind] <- x[ind] - 1

  #Set to values smaller than 1 to zero
  ind <- x < 0
  x[ind] <- 0

  return(x)
}

fun2 <- function(x){
  return(ifelse(x > 0, x - 1, 0))
}

fun3 <- function(x){
  return(pmax(x - 1, 0))
}

set.seed(1234)
x <- round(runif(1e7, -1, 1))

system.time(fun1(x))
#user  system elapsed
#0.17    0.03    0.20

system.time(fun2(x))
#user  system elapsed
#0.55    0.17    0.72

system.time(fun3(x))
#user  system elapsed
#0.08    0.00    0.08
```

Aaron's solution is (by far) the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, it should be very fast:

```
(connections - 1) * (connections >= 1)
```

Comment: Nice, just about the same speed as `pmax` on my machine with the sample data I made up.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you would say

```
ifelse( connections > 0, connections - 1, 0 )
```

but since you do not want negative values to appear, better would be

```
ifelse( connections >= 1, connections - 1, 0 )
```

so values of 0.5 won't get set to -0,5, but to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
> set.seed(0151)
> connections <- rnorm(15)
> 
> connections 
 [1] -0.05153895  0.76573738 -0.14673959 -0.11318581 -0.39551140  0.78227595 -1.39747811 -1.01883832  0.22947586  0.67217297 -0.48455178  0.56060896  0.06615648 -1.34987612
[15] -0.24291581
> 
> connections <- ifelse(connections > 0, connections -1, 0)
> connections
 [1]  0.0000000 -0.2342626  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.2177241  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.7705241 -0.3278270  0.0000000 -0.4393910 -0.9338435  0.0000000  0.0000000
```

Comment: `Error: object 'if_else' not found`; did you mean `ifelse`?

Comment: `if_else` comes from the `dplyr`-package

Comment: yes, if_else is in the `dplyr` package. `ifelse` works.